# Is there an overall trending graph for questions/answers by tag?

Tags: feature-request

Sometimes it is very interesting to see about what people are talking about. How many questions on this theme or other? How many answers? What posts are upvoted?

If it would implemented we can see things like TIOBE supply: 
http://www.tiobe.com/tiobe-index/

Is there an overall trending graph for questions/answers by tag?

Comment: There is a [site analytics privilege](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/site-analytics) which unlocks at 25k rep may be it contains such information.

Comment: In a word: no. (<- That, by the way, is how you use the phrase "in a word", when you're actually using a single word, not a whole sentence :)). You could create queries using the [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) or get the [Stack Exchange data dump](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange) and make your own...

Comment: cross-site duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235145/query-for-the-usage-of-a-tag-over-time/268076#268076